# Getiing field from JSON object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to extract the created_utc from the JSON object can anyone tell me how can I do that in javascript? I do not want to convert it into string and parse word by word is there a quicker method to obtain the created_utc field?

```
var temp = {
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":44,
        "params":{
            "q":"*:*",
            "indent":"on",
            "wt":"json",
            "_":"1491759117819"}},
    "response": {
        "numFound": 2, "start": 0, "docs": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "_version_": 1564222440512421888
            },
            {
                "author": ["illusorywall"],
                "link_id": ["t3_3yy560"],
                "created_utc": [1451606530],
                "subreddit": ["bloodborne"],
                "score": [5],
                "body": ["I don't think it's always the same kind of wall. It can be a larger, sort of \"arched\" section of wall, or a small rectangular section of wall, like a normal doorway. I have seen these two spaces use the same texture though, if that's what you mean by it always being the same type of wall, but I think it can also have a different texture.  I intend to take a screenshot of every one I find to be sure."],
                "id": "4f9a4bc0-4b7b-4aba-8820-187bfd2e6645",
                "_version_": 1564222753474609152
            }]
    }
    };
```

Comment: temp.response.docs[1].created_utc[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:

```
temp.response.docs[1].created_utc[0]
```

### Snippet:

```js
var temp = {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 44,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "indent": "on",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1491759117819"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [{
        "id": "1",
        "_version_": 1564222440512421888
      },
      {
        "author": ["illusorywall"],
        "link_id": ["t3_3yy560"],
        "created_utc": [1451606530],
        "subreddit": ["bloodborne"],
        "score": [5],
        "body": ["I don't think it's always the same kind of wall. It can be a larger, sort of \"arched\" section of wall, or a small rectangular section of wall, like a normal doorway. I have seen these two spaces use the same texture though, if that's what you mean by it always being the same type of wall, but I think it can also have a different texture.  I intend to take a screenshot of every one I find to be sure."],
        "id": "4f9a4bc0-4b7b-4aba-8820-187bfd2e6645",
        "_version_": 1564222753474609152
      }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(temp.response.docs[1].created_utc[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
temp["response"]["docs"][1]["created_utc"][0]